# Run Counter while button press

Tags: swift, button, while-loop, timer

I am very new to swift and I want to make a button work like this:
Press the Button and hold. While the Button is pressed the label value goes up like every second +1 until the button is released.

This is what I get so far:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var counter = 0;
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad();

        }

        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
            if (sender as AnyObject).state != .ended{
                counter+=1;
                // wait 100ms
                self.label.text = String (counter);
            }
        }
    }
```

[This is how I linked it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVY7r.png)

Comment: For starters maybe you should handle two presses of the button instead, one to start the counter and the other one to end it. Either way I think you must use a timer as well

Comment: Don’t use AnyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `UIButton` actions `Touch Down` and `Touch Up Inside`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


var timer : Timer?
var startTime = 0 
var timerReset = true // I don't know what logic you want. This basically has been added so the number is not set to 0 immediately when you release the button. You can also add another button to reset startTime variable and the label

@IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    numberLabel.text = String(startTime) //initial value
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func holdingTheButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("I am holding")
    timerReset = false // reset to false since you are holding the button
    guard timer == nil else { return }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: Any) {
    print("button released")
    startTime = 0
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
    timerReset = true // reset to true since you released. 
}

@objc func updateTime(){
    //update label every second
    print("updating label ")
    if timerReset {
        startTime = 0
    }
    startTime += 1
    numberLabel.text = String(startTime)
} 
}
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure you are connecting in the right way. `Touch Down` has to be used if you want to call the function while you hold the button:

[image]

In your console, you should see this happening if you release the button after 10 SECONDS:

[image]

If you want to have a button to reset, you can just add the it and then connect it to the following function (but also make sure you remove the bool `timeReset` and the if statement inside `updateTime`:

```
@IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: Any) {
  startTime = 0
  numberLabel.text = String(startTime)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mat ! But it doesn't work the way I wanted. When I start the programm with your code, it starts counting when I pressed the label, when I release the button, counter counts up until  I press the button again.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting the button the way I showed you? You have to use touch Down for holdingTheButton function and Touch up inside for buttonReleased. I tested it and it works pefectly.

Comment: I wanted this: WHILE I HOLD the button, the counter should count up and when I release the button, the counter should stop.  And yes, I want to reset it with another button. Greetings and thanks for your effort!!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way the code works for me. When you hold the button it count up until you release it. It then stops. It is weird. You should see this happening in the console. When you hold it should print ""updating label" continuously.

Comment: Oh Okay.. I edited my question and added a screenshot of my Button links.

Comment: HOLD ON I think I see my fault

Comment: You are making a mistake. you have to use Touchdown on holdingTheButton and Touch up inside for the other function

Comment: exactly. So sorry hahahah okayyy thanks a lot!! Now it works perfectly :)

Comment: @RacketCoder If it helped can you please accept the answer?. I am glad it worked.  Happy Coding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using two sent event touch of `UIButton` and a `Timer`.

```
var counter = 0
var timer: Timer?
@IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    print(counter)
}

@IBAction func buttonTouchDown(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(increaseCount), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func increaseCount() {
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
}
```

[image]